# Select Data won't work... Parameters are not valid in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, error-000539, error-000800

I'm creating a model in the ArcGIS 10.3 ModelBuilder and have problems to get the select data tool to work.
At first the complete model: [IHS-Klassifizierung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhPWL.png)
With the **Select Data** tool (Input Data Element: Raster, Child Data Element: %layerband%_1) I'm selecting Band_1 or Band_3 from a Rasterfile, for this I need to check with **Calculate Value** if the Bands are called "Layer_x" or "Band_x" (In my raster data are different names and I mustn't change them), with the following code:

```
def x(Rasterfile):
import arcpy            # I think this is not necessary, but I'm not sure   
desc = arcpy.Describe(Rasterfile)       # Get the necessary information
bandlayer = desc.children[0].name       # select the first band
ergebnis = str(bandlayer.split("_",1)[0])   # Remove the _ and the number from the Name
return ergebnis
```

as Expression I use `x("%Rasterfile%")` and Date type String.

When I run the model on my sample data (just one raster file) I get the following error:

```
Executing: IHS-Klassifizierung W:\arctest W:\arctest\output
Start Time: Tue Nov 03 16:39:06 2015
Executing (Iterate Rasters): IterateRasters W:\arctest # # NOT_RECURSIVE
Start Time: Tue Nov 03 16:39:06 2015
Succeeded at Tue Nov 03 16:39:07 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,52 seconds)
Executing (Parse Path (2)): ParsePath W:\arctest\orthoclip.tif FILE
Start Time: Tue Nov 03 16:39:07 2015
Succeeded at Tue Nov 03 16:39:07 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,00 seconds)
Executing (Calculate Value): CalculateValue x("orthoclip.tif") 
"def x(Rasterfile):\n   
import arcpy                
desc = arcpy.Describe(Rasterfile)       
bandlayer = desc.children[0].name       
ergebnis = str(bandlayer.split("_",1)[0])       
return ergebnis\n" 
String
Start Time: Tue Nov 03 16:39:07 2015
Value = Band
Succeeded at Tue Nov 03 16:39:07 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,04 seconds)
Executing (Select Data): SelectData W:\arctest\orthoclip.tif Band_1
Start Time: Tue Nov 03 16:39:07 2015
**Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.**
**ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of Band_1 | Band_2 | Band_3 | Band_4.**
Failed to execute (Select Data).
Failed to execute (IHS-Klassifizierung).
```

If I try it without the *Calculate Value Tool* and put in the *Select Data- Child Data Element* directly Band_1 or Band_3 it works.

Sometimes it happens (I can't figure out why and I don't connect it to changes witch I made) that the following error appears:

```
Executing: IHS-Klassifizierung W:\arctest W:\arctest\output
Start Time: Wed Nov 04 13:23:47 2015
Executing (Iterate Rasters): IterateRasters W:\arctest # # NOT_RECURSIVE
Start Time: Wed Nov 04 13:23:47 2015
Succeeded at Wed Nov 04 13:23:47 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,35 seconds)
Executing (Parse Path (2)): ParsePath W:\arctest\orthoclip.tif FILE
Start Time: Wed Nov 04 13:23:47 2015
Succeeded at Wed Nov 04 13:23:47 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,00 seconds)
Executing (Calculate Value): CalculateValue x("orthoclip.tif") "def x(Rasterfile):\n    
import arcpy\n  
desc = arcpy.Describe(Rasterfile)       \n  
bandlayer = desc.children[0].name       \n  
ergebnis = bandlayer.split("_",1)[0]        \n  
return ergebnis\n" 
String
Start Time: Wed Nov 04 13:23:47 2015
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: x("orthoclip.tif") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in x
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1246, in Describe
    return gp.describe(value)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 374, in describe
    self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
IOError: "orthoclip.tif" does not exist

Failed to execute (Calculate Value).
Failed at Wed Nov 04 13:23:48 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,28 seconds)
Failed to execute (IHS-Klassifizierung).
Failed at Wed Nov 04 13:23:48 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,93 seconds)
```

Comment: Can you show us the output from when you try it without the Calculate Value Tool and put in the Select Data- Child Data Element directly Band_1 or Band_3 and it works? Does the call to SelectData look any different than what you've shown us (`SelectData W:\arctest\orthoclip.tif Band_1`)?

Comment: That's what I tried before, it works without problems,
`Executing (Select Data): SelectData W:\arctest\orthoclip.tif Band_1
Succeeded at Wed Nov 04 13:16:25 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,04 seconds)
Executing (Select Data (2)): SelectData W:\arctest\orthoclip.tif Band_3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: In this case it's stupid to use the "Select Data" tool, because you can use directly the calculate value tool for getting the complete paths to the Bands. [image: Changed Model]

The python code from calculate value tool (expression x(r"%Raster%"), DataType Raster Band):

```
def x(rasterimage):
    import arcpy
    desc = arcpy.Describe(rasterimage)
    bandlayer = desc.children[0].name
    ergebnis = bandlayer.split("_",1)[0]
    pfad = r"%Raster%\%s_1" % ergebnis
    return pfad
```

Works fine now.